# Express 4 route not hit

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running Express 4. Inside app.js I got:

```
var products = require('./routes/products');
var app = express();
app.use('/products', products);
```

Then, in routes/products:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //Some Code. Ok
});

router.get('/:code', function(req, res) {
    //Some code. Not hit
});
```

My problem is that the second route is never hit when called with the code parameter, it always hit /

http://localhost:3000/products?code=123 goes to /

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how you call it the way your router is written: `http://localhost:3000/products/123` should get you there. Otherwise you'd use the first form, and look at `req.query`

Comment: @barry-johnson comment above is the correct answer.

Comment: @barry-johnson Thanks for your response. Write your comment as an answer to mark it as resolved

Comment: @barry-johnson By the way, how to set up the route in order to receive code as a query string parameter?

Comment: @Oscar - I just added an answer which should explain both the `req.query` and `req.params` approaches to handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the way the router is written, you would invoke it as with `http://localhost:3000/product/123` and this would cause the value `"123"` to be available inside your handler at `req.params.code`.

To do what you want to do, you would use the first router you have defined, which you are already binding to the `/products` path with your app.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    if (req.query.code !== undefined) {
        // do something here if there was a parameter
    } else {
        // your original '/products' code here...
        //Some Code. Ok
    }
});
```

Basically: `req.params` is for parameters coded into the main URL (i.e. on the left side of the '?') while `req.query` is for the extracted querystring parameters.

You can read a bit more about how `req.query` works - i.e. the manner in which it extracts the querystring into the req.query object on the [express doc for it](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query). Also worth reading up on [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params) so you know both your options.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/:code', ...)
```

matches a route like

```
http://localhost:3000/123
```

The `router.get()` routing matches things in the URL, not in the query string.  To process `http://localhost:3000/products?code=123` as a route, you should do:

```
router.get('/products', ...)`
```

and then in your route handler examine the query string to see what value `code` has.

```
 router.get('/products', function(req, res) {
      // access req.query.code here to get the value of `?code=123
      console.log(req.query.code);         // 123
 });
```

Express documentation for req.query [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).